# Reading multiple text files to do automated text analysis

Tags: r, text, readlines

I want to read multiple text files to do an automated text analysis. My files are txt files, and I used list.files to list all of the files in the directory. Each text file is news article . The code looks like this.

```
lff <- list.files(path = "the path", pattern = paste('*.txt*',sep=""), full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE)
df<-ldply(lff, readLines)
```

I used readLines for reading my texts, but this command gives me an error like following.

```
Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels")) : 
Results do not have equal lengths
```

read.table is not appropriate for my analysis. I am finding anyway to import these texts for each line.

** I tried

```
   df<-ldply(lff, readLines(warn=FALSE))
```

but it took forever to import these files. I only have 300+ files, so it should not take this long. What is the problem?

**

Each file looks like this.

*This past week's debate before the Palm Beach County Commission over funding for a spring training stadium looked a little like the debate that has been going on in Brevard County over how much to do the keep the Washington Nationals spring training in Viera. Only the numbers were bigger.*

Because I have the list of my 300+ files, I have 300+ rows in the `lff` object. I want to import each text in each row. I am going to also add some additional data for each row like the date and author of each article.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you paste a small case of your text files here? I can't reach your idea, what is the structure you want supporting your following analysis? (`ldply` will give you a `data.frame`, can you explain which `fields` will construct the `data.frame`? )

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what *article* is (is it a *file* or a *row* ?), but I think you will need this.

```
df <- ldply(lff, function(file) {
  content <- readLines(file)
  date <- smth_date
  author <- smth_author
  data.frame(content = content, date = date, author = author, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
})
```

PS: don't forget that `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, auto-converted factors always give me unexpected bugs.